# How to remove string between multiple sets of parentheses with regexreplace?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, re2

I'm working in Google Spreadsheets and have a cell with multiple sets of closed parentheses and I want to remove all sets of the parentheses.

For example, a cell might have:
`Public transport (Bus, train), Driving (car, motorcycle)`

And I want it to be this instead:
`Public transport, Driving`

I'm pretty sure I need a regexreplace formula to make this work. I tried this formula:
`=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\(.+\)","")` but it only replaces the first set of parentheses and returns: `Public transport`

How do I modify the regular expression so that it keeps the whole string but removes all sets of parentheses? The cells can have anywhere from 0 to 8 sets of parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Try making the dot in your regex non greedy:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "\(.+?\)", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, " \(.+?\)", )
```

it will render properly the space before comma

[image]